# Jquery lazyload plugin and callback function

Tags: jquery

i download jquery lazyload plugin from this site http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload.

from their doc i have not found that one can use any callback or not with lazyload plugin.

suppose my html look like

```
<div id="gallery" class="busy"><img src="blah.jpg" /></div>
<div id="gallery" class="busy"><img src="blah2.jpg" /></div>
<div id="gallery" class="busy"><img src="blah3.jpg" /></div>
```

my script like

```
$("#gallery img").lazyload();
```

class busy will just set a busy image at the center of div. so i need a callback and from the callback i need to detect image download completed or not if completed then i just remove the class from corresponding parent div of image tag .

so please show me the way to implement callback with lazyload and also need sample code by which i can remove the class from corresponding parent div of image tag .

thanks

Comment: ur html markup is wrong, ID has to be unique for different divs

Comment: i asked different issue that is there any callback function which fire everytime when download complete of each images?

Answer (score 12):

I had the same question. Did some searching, came here, and found the answer. This is wat I have, and works for me:

```
$(this).lazyload({
    effect : 'fadeIn',
    load : function()
    {
        console.log($(this)); // Callback here
    }
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Wonderful! Works smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Rick de Graaf's answer almost did it for me.

The problem for me was: **Load gets called for the placeholder images as well**. Which in my case was a problem. I wanted to add a class to the final loaded images only. I added this to make it work for me:

```
jQuery("img.lazy").lazyload({   
            effect : 'fadeIn',
            load : function()
            {
                if ( jQuery(this).attr("src") != "data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhZABlAIAAAPn5+QAAACH5BAAAAAAALAAAAABkAGUAAAJ0hI+py+0Po5y02ouz3rz7D4biSJbmiabqyrbuC8fyTNf2jef6zvf+DwwKh8Si8YhMKpfMpvMJjUqn1Kr1is1qt9yu9wsOi8fksvmMTqvX7Lb7DY/L5/S6/Y7P6/f8vv8PGCg4SFhoeIiYqLjI2Oj4CBnZVQAAOw==") {
                    jQuery(this).addClass("visible-image");                 
                }
            }
        });
```

If the loaded image is the data:image, don't do anything, else add my class.