# Jquery resize function not working when trying to resize images loaded after document ready

Tags: jquery

I have a plugin which loads images after document ready.

In order for it to work, the image source looks like this:

The script shows the **loader.gif** until the image is loaded and then replaces that gif with **the_actual_image.jpg**

Here is how I call the function:

```
function mylazyload() {
    $("img.lazy").show();
    var timeout = setTimeout(function(){$(".models img.lazy").lazyload({effect : "fadeIn"})}, 800);
}
```

I have a re-size function which I call after the mylazyload(); function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){      
    mylazyload();
    resize_images();
});
```

Here is the re-size function:

```
function resize_images() {
    var maxHeight = $(".defx img").height();
    $(".model img.lazy").each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.height() > maxHeight || $this.height() < maxHeight) {
            $this.removeAttr('style').css("height","auto");
            $this.css('height', maxHeight);
        }
    });
}
```

The **PROBLEM** is that the resize function seems to work on the **loader.gif**, not resizing **the_actual_image.jpg**.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1:**

Your lazy load is asynchronous and have a timeout on it. Therefore if you call like this:

```
lazyload();
resize();
```

The resize function will occour before the lazyload is even triggered.

**2:**

If you do:

```
setTimeout(
   function() {
    $(".models img.lazy").lazyload({effect: "fadeIn"});
    resize();
   },
   800
);
```

I think it will work in localhost, but it's not gonna work in production, because browsers load images asynchronous too.

**3:**

So what you need is a callback in the lazyload function. Maybe the library you use have it implemented like:

```
$(".models img.lazy").lazyload({
      effect: "fadeIn",
      callback: resize()
});
```

But I'm not sure. You have to look for it and if you dont find write your own lazy loading or change for another library.

**4:**

Based on the response that you found:

```
setTimeout(
    function() {
        $(".models img.lazy").lazyload({
            effect: "fadeIn",
            load: function () {
                resize_images();
            }
        });
    },
    800
);
```

Comment: Any ideas hot to do it? Ty very much

Comment: Could this be it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8557720/jquery-lazyload-plugin-and-callback-function

Comment: Yes, but I am a such a newb:) not sure how to modify my function in order for it to work: console.log($(this)); // Callback here
 what is this? I am pretty sure I cannot use the jqery each in my resize function now

Comment: But I'm not very sure why you have that timeout function. I'm pretty sure that you don't need it.

Comment: I have a loading gif and the images are loaded from external urls, I have noticed the site working better with it.

Comment: Don't i have to modify the resize function also?

Comment: ah ok! =D
please vote the guy up on that question (because it helped us) and don't forget to mark as answer if it solves your problem.

Comment: I am testing it now, but I'm pretty sure the resize function needs to be modified

Comment: I have applied it, but now the images that need resizing disappeared. So the callback works, but the resizing function needs modifying I think. Ty:)

Comment: I didn't look there, but it's another problem. Let me see. =D

Comment: You are a great help, I have a deadline for this project and this last thing holds me up

Comment: Change the load: `function () { resize_images(); }` for `load: function () { alert('working'); };` and check if it's working. If yes, then we move from there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16331/discussion-between-lolol-and-webmasters)

Answer (score -1):

Your images are not yet loaded on the DOM Ready statement.

Try adding the resize in your timeout as well:

```
setTimeout(function(){$(".models img.lazy").lazyload({effect : "fadeIn"});
resize_images();
}, 800);
```